# 13.04 plus chrome = video with audio at too high of a pitch

Tags: sound, google-chrome

It doesnt happen at first, but ive tried this twice.  At first the audio is fine, but eventually the audio goes to where everything sounds like an alvin and the chipmunks record.  It stays in sync with the video, but the audio is too high.  Restarts do not fix the issue.

Comment: I believe this to be a Chrome-related bug, and (off-hand) recall seeing this bug reported by another user within the past two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.
Any time it went wrong I used

```
pulseaudio -k
```

in the terminal. It shut the sound off for a couple of seconds, and then when I open chrome again, the problem is fixed. It seems to be an intermittent problem - are you running kernel 3.8.0-23 perchance?

Comment: FYI, I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, kernel 3.8.0-24, and Chrome 28.0.1500.29

Comment: Seems like the issue hasn't been fixed for the newest revision of the kernel then. If it's an issue with Chrome as suggested above, perhaps install a newer (development) or older (stable) version of Chrome, if the pulseaudio thing doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

2 days ago, when it first occurred on my workstation, I solved it by disabling the VLC Multimedia Plugin. for the moment [Kent Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/164383/kentgeek)'s solution works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu virhilius! You should mention the steps you took to disable the VLC Multimedia Plugin in your answer, so that the person that asked the question (or anyone else in the future) can know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Alaa. So, introduce 
**chrome://plugins/** in chrome's address bar. hit enter and the page will display the browser's plug-ins. Check for 
VLC Multimedia Plugin in the list and press Disable. In my case, after restarting the browser the problem was solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! However, you can actually edit your own answer by hitting the `edit` button right underneath your answer. So you may do that, and include the steps there. That way, it's much clearer because people might miss the comments.